# Python app to django web app

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-models

I've written some python code to accomplish a task. Currently, there are 4-5 classes that I'm storing in separate files. I'd now like to change this whole thing into a database-backed web app. I've been reading tutorials on Django, and so far I get the impression that I'll need to manually specify the fields and their types for every "model" that I use. This is a little surprising to me, since I was expecting some kind of ORM capability that would just take the existing classes I've already defined, and map them onto a database somehow, in a manner abstracted away from me.

Is this not the case? Am I missing something? It looks like I need to specify all the fields and types in the file 'models.py'.

Okay, now beyond those specifics, does anyone have any general tips on the best way to migrate an object-oriented desktop application to a web application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That *is* Django's ORM: it maps classes to tables. What else did you expect? There needs to be some way of specifying what the fields are, though, before you can use them, and that's managed through the `models.Model` class and the various `models.Field` subclasses. You can certainly use your classes as mixins in order to use the existing business logic on top of the field definitions.

Comment: okay that's kind of ridiculous. I'm using some fairly complex classes and some external libraries that use their own even more complex classes. Are you suggesting that I have to manually pore through each of these classes and boil them down into a database schema composed of simple tables and fields, and that the ORM can't do that for me? That would be very unfortunate if true.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about a database backend based web app, you **have to** specify what fields of the data you want to store and what type of the value you want stored.

There is an abstraction that introspects the db to convert it into the django models.py format. But I know not of any that introspects a python class and stores arbitrary data into db. How would that even work? Are the objects, now, stored as a pickle?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to check the output, but you can have Django automatically create models from existing databases through one-time introspection.

Taken from the link below, you would set up your database in settings.py, and then call

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

This will dump the sample models.py file to standard out for your inspection. In order to create the file, simply redirect the output

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

See for more:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/?from=olddocs#auto-generate-the-models